# How to add a click through link to an embedded vimeo video?

Tags: css, iframe, href, embed, vimeo

I have used the following code to embed a vimeo video on my site:

```
<div style="padding:56.25% 0 0 0;position:relative;">

<iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/477531257?background=1&autoplay=1&loop=1&title=0&byline=0&portrait=0" style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;width:100%;height:100%;" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; fullscreen" allowfullscreen></iframe>

</div><script src="https://player.vimeo.com/api/player.js"></script>
```

How could I redirect the user to the video URL when the user clicks on it?

Answer (score 0):

you can use anchor tag

```html
<a href=""></a>
```

and give the web address in quotation marks in the href.
if resolves your problem let me know and up vote.

Comment: Thanks!

Unfortunately I couldn't get this to work!

Am I placing the href in the wrong place?

Comment: @davidjsbrown you have to put iframe tag in anchor tag in order to get the desired output

Answer (score 0):

Wrap it in a `a tag` and put your link in their. like this:

```
<a href="/yourlink">
<div style="padding:56.25% 0 0 0;position:relative;">

<iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/477531257?background=1&autoplay=1&loop=1&title=0&byline=0&portrait=0" style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;width:100%;height:100%;" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; fullscreen" allowfullscreen></iframe>

</div><script src="https://player.vimeo.com/api/player.js"></script>
</a>
```

And add `pointer-events: none;` to your `iframe`:

`iframe { pointer-events: none; }`

Comment: Hey thanks! 

I've added the code and updated the url but the video is not clickable. 

https://www.davidjackspencer.co/

It is the top video on this page if that helps. 

Password to view site is DJSB2020PORTFOLIO

Thanks!!

Comment: Thanks for letting me check your site. I have forgotten 1 thing! You need to add `pointer-events: none;` to the `iframe`. I have also eddited my awnser! Good luck.

Comment: @davidjsbrown in your css, on your iframe (check my posted awnser). Or use inline css, like this: `<iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/477531257?background=1&autoplay=1&loop=1&title=0&byline=0&portrait=0" style="pointer-events:none;position:absolute;top:0;left:0;width:100%;height:100%;" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; fullscreen" allowfullscreen></iframe>`

Comment: You hero! 

Thanks so much!

Comment: @davidjsbrown No problem! Can you mark my awnser as the correct one? Thank you!